# How can I push Instagram messages to a channel in Microsoft Teams as notification

Tags: instagram, microsoft-teams

I know that this request might be not solved, but if someone made it or has idea how to make it please help.

I am working in professional floor and I am not allowed to reply or to check Instagram every min. I need to have the messages from Instagram to a channel in Microsoft Teams to identify if it's worth to get out of the floor or not (just to reply and then get back to work again.) - the point here (i don't want to check my phone in the floor)

I have created the channel itself

[image: Channel on Teams]

And then clicked on connectors and hoped to find the Instagram application there but not found.
But i know that somehow we can connect between Microsoft applications and the social media applications using the power automate, and i saw a lot of templates in power automate includes the Instagram application.
I hope that there is an answer for this issue.

Best Regards,

Comment: You can send notification to Teams using [Incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet). You have to write your custom logic for fetching messages from Instagram and pass to the webhook.

Answer (score 1):

You can send notification to Teams using [Incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet). You have to write your custom logic for fetching messages from Instagram and pass to the webhook.